# Step in Spivak's proof that derivative of a $f: \mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^m}$ is unique

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

On page 16 of Spivak's *[Calculus on Manifolds](http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~marcio/ps2009/spivak)*,Spivak proves the derivative of a function $f: \mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^m}$ is unique if it exists. The last line of the proof is $$0=lim_{t\to{0}}\frac{|\lambda{(tx)}-\mu{(tx)}|}{|tx|}=\frac{|\lambda{(x)}-\mu{(x)}|}{|x|},$$ but I don't understand why $$lim_{t\to{0}}\frac{|\lambda{(tx)}-\mu{(tx)}|}{|tx|}=\frac{|\lambda{(x)}-\mu{(x)}|}{|x|}.$$

Does anyone know why? Is it because $|t|$ factors out of the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Yes: both $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are linear so $|t|$ can be factored out.

Comment: @Ovi, yeah it's not that. The proof depends on it being what's written, because Spivak's trying to show that $|\lambda{(x)}-\mu{(x)}|=0$ $\forall{x}\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x\neq{0}$.

Comment: Spivak is proving the uniqueness of the derivative. If you follow it step by step, you'll see that the result  follows from the assumptions that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are both derivatives of $f$.

Answer (score 3):

You omitted important parts of the proof preceding that statement. Before the statement, Spivak proves that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lambda(h)-\mu(h)}{|h|}=0$. And as you recognized, we can factor out $|t|$ on both sides. Hence, since $x\neq 0$ in this case, we must have $|\lambda(x)-\mu(x)|=0$.

Comment: Yeah I understood that, just didn't understand why the equality above held. Thanks anyway though!